# How to display the results based on their parent selection in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to display only the corresponding items on selection of its parent (similar to if country is selected then its corresponding states should display) for that i have this below code but the problem is i am not able to apply the filtering. Can anybody help me resolve in this?

See the code below: (The below code is for first tile on selection of this i am showing below its corresponding account related data)

```
<div class="col mb-3" *ngFor="let account of cloudAccounts1">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="item-card text-dark mat-elevation-z8">
                                    <div class="text-center" (click)="getInstances($event, account)"
                                        [ngClass]="{'bg-info text-white': entry.account == account}">
                                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'AZURE'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" src="assets/images/azure.png" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'AWS'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" src="assets/images/aws.png" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'GCP'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" src="assets/images/gcp.png" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="mt-2"> {{account.accountType}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer no-border py-3">
                                            <div class="text-truncate">{{account.name}}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
```

The below code is for which when i select any of the above account say AWS or AZURE or GCP then only its corresponding tile should display. The below code.

```
<div class="col-md-2" *ngIf="showRegion">
                        <br />
                        <div class="h6">Instance Type</div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col mb-3" *ngFor="let account of cloudAccounts2">
                                <a href="javascript:;" class="item-card text-dark mat-elevation-z8">
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <div class="card-header py-3">
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'AWS'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" title="{{account.name}}"
                                                    src="assets/images/aws.png">&nbsp;
                                                <div>{{account.accountType}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'AZURE'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" title="{{account.name}}"
                                                    src="assets/images/azure.png">&nbsp;
                                                <div>{{account.accountType}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div *ngIf="account.accountType === 'GCP'">
                                                <img class="img-responsive h-25 w-25" title="{{account.name}}"
                                                    src="assets/images/gcp.png">&nbsp;
                                                <div>{{account.accountType}}</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="card-footer py-3 no-border text-truncate">{{account.name}} &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="{{account.link}}" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
</div>
```

In cloudAccounts2 array, i have this data, i need to show only one tile on selection of its parent account. But instead its showing all 3 tiles which i dont want.

```
cloudAccounts1 = [{ "id": "8a8080fc710cdc140171104216c2002b", "accountType": "AWS" },
{ "id": "8a8080fc710cdc140171104216c2002b", "accountType": "AZURE" },
{ "id": "8a8080fc710cdc140171104216c2002b", "accountType": "GCP" }]
```

Based on the above selection i need to display only its corresponding below data.

```
cloudAccounts2 = [{"accountType":"AWS", "name":"T2.micro", "link":"https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/"},
                    {"accountType":"AZURE", "name":"STANDARD_A1", "link":"https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/linux/"},
                    {"accountType":"GCP", "name":"n1-standard-1", "link":"https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing"}
                  ];
```

This is the method where i am handling the logic to display only the selected values to display in the template. Can anybody let me know what is my mistake?

```
 getInstances(event, instanceSelected) {
    this.classToggled = false;
    this.entry.account = instanceSelected;
    if(this.entry.account.accountType === instanceSelected.accountType){
      this.showInstance = true;
      // this.cloudAccounts2 = [];
      // this.cloudAccounts2 = [instanceSelected];
      if(instanceSelected.accountType === this.cloudAccounts2[1].accountType){
        this.cloudAccounts2[1].accountType = instanceSelected.accountType;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: please create a stackblitz for it.

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to do.
I can say that this code is completely redundant because if those value are equal then theres no point to setting them to each other

  if(instanceSelected.accountType === this.cloudAccounts2[1].accountType){
        this.cloudAccounts2[1].accountType = instanceSelected.accountType;
      }

Comment: Hey shashank, please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nh4pq6

Comment: @Harry, Actually what i am trying to do is say for example if select the parent AWS or AZURE account then i want to show only its related account in the below section. I mean in the below tile or div whatever it is. But as i am looping through then its displaying all the accounts irrespective of it selection.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do an `NgIf` within a loop to select your item. Instead of doing that you can create new objects for your selected account (see component) and instead of `getInstances()` on click do `selectAccount1()`

Html:

```
<div *ngFor="let account of cloudAccounts1">
  <a (click)="selectAccount1(account)">
    ...
  </a>
</div>

<div *ngFor="let account of cloudAccounts2">
  <a (click)="selectAccount2(account)">
    ...
  </a>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedAccount1">
  <ul>
    <li>id: {{ selectedAccount1.id }}</li>
    <li>accountType: {{ selectedAccount1.accountType }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedAccount2">
  <ul>
    <li>accountType : {{ selectedAccount2.accountType }} </li>:
    <li>name: {{ selectedAccount2.name }}</li>
    <li>link: {{ selectedAccount2.link }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Component:

```
public selectedAccount1: any;
public selectedAccount2: any;

public selectAccount1(account: any): void {
   this.selectedAccount1 = account;
}

public selectAccount2(account: any): void {
   this.selectedAccount2 = account;
}
```